# Sort bean list using custom annotation in Brightspot DARI

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort List using annotation. so is there any annotation so i can sort my list by date? or is there any possibility to create custom annotation ?

Note: I am not using jpa or hibernate things. i am using bright-spot (DARI framework )

My code looks like.

```
 public class Student {
  private String name;
  private Date dob;
}
```

My Second class

```
public class School {
  private String name;
  private List<Student> students; // here i want to sort list 
}
```

Comment: Instead of vote down please give some suggestions it will be help full to some one. Thank  you

Comment: It might help if you explain in the question what Brightspot is with a link to the documentation of the version you use, and that it uses a lot of annotations, and that's why you want to sort by annotation. In pain java, there is no useful quick solution.

Comment: Do you need to use those libraries?

Comment: Not my downvote btw. Sorting with Brightspot also is documented for queries http://docs.brightspot.com/dari/querying/sorting.html

Comment: If not, you can just define an natural order for the student class, then  sort it. Or, you can pass a comparator od students to the sort algorithm. Or, you can put then in a TreeSet, so it will allways be sorted

Answer (score 0):

Does the documented `ToolUi.DefaultSortField` do what you want?

```
@ToolUi.DefaultSortField("dob")
public class Student extends Content  {

    private String name;

    @Indexed
    private Date dob;

}
```

See http://docs.brightspot.com/cms/developers-guide/content-modeling/content-modeling-annotations.html#toolui-defaultsortfield